# Run code after exporting PDF with CrystalReports on ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, page-refresh, export-to-pdf

I'm doing a website on ASP.NET, and I have some textboxes and a GridView with some rows, that receives data from a SQL connection, and an asp:Button to "Export to PDF", using Crystal Reports. When I click on the button, I want to export to PDF the information from the GridView, and that is happening successfully. The problem, in the other hand, is that after I click the button, I also want to run a SQL query to delete the rows from the table on SQL that is giving data do the gridview, bind the gridview again to update it, and turn the visibility of the textboxes to false. Basically, restart the page (not to do a PostBack, literally restart). Is that possible? Because as of now, the page blocks after exporting the PDF (I guess because it returns a Response.End internally after doing so). Here's the code:

```
protected void ExportToPDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
                ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
                crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport1.rpt"));

                ExportFormatType formatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                crystalReport.ExportToHttpResponse(formatType, Response, true, "test.pdf");

                // THIS CODE BELOW DOESN'T RUN ANYMORE

                // This deletes the sql table
                int AntiError2 = service.CleanShoppingCart();
                if (AntiError2 > 0)
                {
                    //this refreshes the states I want
                    this.BindGridCart();
                    Session.Clear();

                    lineSeparator.Visible = false;
                    imageWithDetails.Visible = false;
                    Items.Visible = false;

                    txtNombre.Text = "";
                    txtDireccion.Text = "";
                    TextBoxObservaciones.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key_name", "alert('Error');", true);
                }
```

The asp:Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="ExportPDF" runat="server" Text="Export to PDF" class="btn btn-success" Font-Bold="true" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to export?');" OnClick="ExportToPDF" formtarget="_blank"></asp:Button>
```

I've tried to open this in a new page with formtarget, I've also tried without it, it never works because of the export, that blocks the rest of the page. My question would be, is there a form, in AJAX or Javascript, to async run the rest of the code, or to download the pdf there, and then run the rest of the code on the server side? If so, could you please show me how? I really need help on this, I've researched for it for hours now, and didn't discovered a valid solution.

I've also tried to export first to byte stream and put that in HTTP header, but it just opens the pdf on the page, doesn't download it nor runs the rest of the code. I've tried using AJAX to call a webservice to just download the PDF from the client-side, but it was returning Internal Server Error.

Thanks.